# Securing a public api using openid connect

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

Good day!

I am currently facing the issue with my asp net core MVC 2.2 application. I have extended the login to use SSO using OpenID Connect with Azure AD. All works great, but I have also a public Rest API, which I do not understand, how the securing could work, without any UI to achieve the handshake principle with the redirects.

Maybe someone could delete me in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what you need is some kind of primer on how Open ID Connect works with APIs and authentication in general. Microsoft has a nice explanation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc

Answer (score 1):

In the REST API you typically use the UseJwtBearer handler to verify that the access token it receives from the MVC client is valid.

So, the MVC client sends its access token to the REST API and the UseJwtBearer will create an ClaimsPrincipal user out of the token (if the token is valid). Then that user is passed to the authorization handler that will determine if the request is ok or not.

Some links:

- https://codeburst.io/jwt-auth-in-asp-net-core-148fb72bed03
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thank for your post, but I am not sure if this really helps. Maybe I was not specific enough. I want to use my Azure credentials to access the public rest API, without using any UI or MVC. E.g Postman or curl

Comment: well, you need to be a bit more specific in your question, how is that API protected? basic auth? bearer JWT tokens? API-key? how?

Comment: Using session token